# How to get the JSON formated WebService format from using URL of an web page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, web-services

I **`have an URL of a login page it goes to the login screen in web.`**

Now I need to get the JSON format of the web page using the URL I have.

And then I can parse it and display in table..

So 1st ***`I need to get the JSON format of the web page using the URL I have.`***

***`How to create a webservice in json response for page`***

**I want to get the "UserName" key and "PassWord" keys in correct format/case sencitive**

Comment: wht u have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Web Service for login page which return JSON response, and than parse that response using SBJSON library. in either NSDictionary or in NSArray. And use that array to populate your TableView.

[This](http://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2012/03/iphoneios-programming-login-screen-post-data-url-parses-json-response/) link contain all the data, from creating Web Service for login to parse JSON I have used it in my project and its really great.

Happy coding.

Comment: in 5th page of this blog he gives you the webservices data.

Comment: yes i tried, but how did i know the format of json values
like "UserName" "PassWord" and some other values...! They may be some other valuse like "EmployeeName" "EmployeeID"

Comment: String *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[txtUsername text],[txtPassword text]];
    Fine, but "username" KEY may diffrent like "EmployeeName" etc how shd i know

Comment: If you are making that Web sevices than definatelly you know that what is the value of that field right. you have to do that customization by your self.i have extended it for 5 field bcoz of my need.

Comment: see this code `if($_POST['username'] == 'dipinkrishna' && $_POST['password'] == 'password') ` in web services this difine the value of that key like `username` or `password`. You can change this field in webservice like `employee ID` or `employee NAme`

Comment: Then your this code `String *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[txtUsername text],[txtPassword text]];` will be like this `String *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"employeeName=%@&EmployeeID=%@",[txtUsername text],[txtPassword text]];`